# Swift UI NavigationLink for visionOS

Tags: swiftui-navigationlink, visionos

I can't for the life of me get NavigationLink to aesthetically work for me. The navigation to the desired view is working just fine, it's the link itself that is expanding beyond the image.  Goal is to have users tap on the image and they're taken to the "FenderXperience" view. Currently you can tap on the image or NavigationLink bar to get there.  I just need the blasted NavigationLink bar to disappear and have only the image represented.  Thanks!

[X Code Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYg94.png)

```
import SwiftUI

struct BrandImage: View {
    var body: some View {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                NavigationStack {
                    Text("Ralph Lauren")
                        .font(.title)
                        .padding(.bottom, -5)
                    
                    Image("RL")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0)
                                .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2))
                    
                            Text("Fender")
                                .font(.title)
                                .padding(.bottom, -5)
                            
                    **NavigationLink(destination: FenderXperience()) {
                        Image("Fender II")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 300, height: 95)
                            .overlay(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0)
                                    .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2))
                    }**
                    
                    Text("Burton")
                        .font(.title)
                        .padding(.bottom, -5)
                    
                    Image("Burton")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0)
                                .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2))
                    
                    Text("Ray Ban")
                        .font(.title)
                        .padding(.bottom, -5)
                    
                    Image("Ray Ban")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0)
                                .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2))
                    
                    Text("Levi's")
                        .font(.title)
                        .padding(.bottom, -5)
                    
                    Image("Levis II")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0)
                                .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2))
                }
            }
            .padding(.leading, 50)
    }
}

#Preview {
    BrandImage()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Structure your NavigationLinks with a label and then change the width of the frame per below.  This solved my issue of making the oval behind the image disappear.

```
NavigationLink {
                    FenderXperience()
                } label: {
                    Image("Fender II")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 95)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0)
                                .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2))
                }
                .frame(width: 250)
```